# How to get the ruby or mutant chicken?

Tags: chickens

In Chickens, how do you get the Ruby chicken or mutant chicken? The code is so confusing when you get the scroll from the portal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you give the trader's friend an emerald chicken nugget, he gives you a clue that it's been encoded through three ciphers:

1. Rail Fence (3-rail rail-fence)
2. ****64 (Base64)
3. Julius (Caesar)

The code from the scroll is:

> 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lJdcxBklJZFVB1lhdg1BBkx9pdBgIJxBFdIVgddJZB4ABNNBBhJhgd51wlhgclBhBF4MMxk5g1BllhBZAMxddJZBBlwlZJEQx9BthVAcZB1lJtchlZhIldFdF8xkBB11BNBlBBkJgVBNghBZA1BAllBg1B1BkMxddJZAAtglE

Running it through a reverse rail-cipher gives:

> 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

Decoding that as base64 gives:

> Pikirh wecw xlex xli pikirhevc qyxerx glmgoir hsiwr'x pmzi mr xli glmgoirzivwi, fyx mr ersxliv hmqirwmsr reqih "Glmgoirzivwi z2.0" (M orsa csy ampp xlmro xlex m'q nsomrk, fyx xlex mw vieppc xli reqi). Xs ks xlivi, nywx wmqtpc irxiv xli tsvxep xs xli glmgoirzivwi ew ywyep, fyx fvmrk 1234 glmgoir rykkixw erh 567 mvsr glmgoir rykkixw (xipitsvxexmsr hizmgi asr'x asvo xlivi), fc fvmrkmrk xlswi mxiqw mr xli ibegx weqi eqsyrx, xli tsvxep ampp fi "fykkih" erh ampp fvmrk csy xs xli Glmgoirzivwi 2.0 Kssh pygo!

And finishing with a Caesar cipher gives:

> Legend says that the legendary mutant chicken doesn't live in the chickenverse, but in another dimension named "Chickenverse v2.0" (I know you will think that i'm joking, but that is really the name). To go there, just simply enter the portal to the chickenverse as usual, but bring 1234 chicken nuggets and 567 iron chicken nuggets (teleportation device won't work there), by bringing those items in the exact same amount, the portal will be "bugged" and will bring you to the Chickenverse 2.0 Good luck!